# npm ERR! when trying to install gulp-jshint

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to install a npm package I receive the error:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Jamie:gulp Egen$ npm install gulp-jshint –save-dev
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/Egen/Code/gulp/–save-dev
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp-jshint" "–save-dev"
npm ERR! node v5.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3

npm ERR! The header content contains invalid characters
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I've set the right permissions at /usr/local/lib/node_modules like this:

```
sudo chown -R Egen /usr/local/
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is a result of an incorrect command. You typed:

```
npm install gulp-jshint -save-dev
```

This causes `npm` to try to install the packages `gulp` and `-save-dev`.

The correct command should be:

```
npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev
```